# An integral involving the argument of the Gamma function and the Riemann Hypothesis

Tags: cv.complex-variables, integration, riemann-zeta-function, riemann-hypothesis

> Evaluate $$I=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t\arg
>  \Gamma(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{it}{2})}{(\frac{1}{4}+t^2)^2}\mathrm{d}t$$
>    where $\Gamma(s)=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x}x^{s-1}\mathrm{d}x.$

Note that $I$ converges since $\Gamma(s)\sim s\log s$. I tried Wolfram Alpha, but it hasn't given me an answer after almost 90 minutes of computation,  hence perhaps will never do.

PS: Migrated from https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3045147

Comment: Did you try to use that $\arg$ is the imaginary part of $\log$?

Comment: Its numeric value equals $-1.6206092975417 $. Isn't it enough?

Comment: @OneTwoOne No. This not disproof the Riemann hypothesis.  when one uses $\arg\zeta(1/2+ix)$ one refers to the "discontinuous" arg defined in a certain specific way.  Your formula for $\arg\zeta(1/2+it)$ is not correct. It is only an equality $\bmod \pi$

Comment: @OneTwoOne It is not so easy to explain. It is defined in the book by Titchmarsh Section 9.3. $\arg\zeta(1/2+iT)$ is obtained by continuous variation along the straight lines joining 2, $2+iT$, $1/2+iT$, starting with the value $0$.  It is a discontinuous function.  While $\arg\Gamma(1/4+it/2)$ is usually meaning as the continuous argument. So the relation you writes between then is not true.

Comment: @OneTwoOne This discontinuous function that uses user 64494 is not the same as you consider.  RH is much more difficult than you think.

Comment: @OneTwoOne  What you have done have nothing to do with the Riemann Hypothesis.  $\arg\zeta(1/2+it)$ contains many information about the zeros.  $\Gamma(1/4+it/2)$ almost nothing.

Comment: @OneTwoOne $\frac{x}{2}\log\pi-\arg\Gamma(1/4+it/2)$ is a very simple function, continuous and indefinitely differentiable.  $\arg\zeta(1/2+ix)$ is continuous except at zeros of zeta (to simplify I assume the Riemann Hypothesis here) the function has jumps at the zeros of zeta.  The equality you write is only  true $\mod \pi$. But if you consider the function of user 64494

Comment: ... then you are making the $\arg\Gamma(1/4+it/2)$ discontinuous at certain points, but not the zeros of zeta. Nevertheless the two functions will be equal modulo $\pi$.

Comment: Consider the principal branch of the logarithm on $\mathbb{C}\setminus(-\infty,0]$. Let $\rho$ be a third root of unity. Check that $\log\rho^2$ is not equal to $2\log\rho$. Think about the reasons.

Comment: @juan, the singularities at the zeros $x_i$ can be treated/circumvented by considering $\lim_{\delta \rightarrow 0^+} (x_{i} + \delta)$. See the addendum.

Comment: @OneTwoOne  Your reasoning is not correct. The difference between $\arg\zeta(1/2+it)$ and the other expression you equals it is not bounded. Some argument of a complex number and another one may differ in any multiple of $2\pi$. We know this is not bounded.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

We prove that 
$$I=-\frac{\pi}{4}(\gamma+\log 4).$$
$$I=\int_0^\infty\frac{t\arg\Gamma(\frac14+\frac{it}{2})}{(\frac14+t^2)^2}\,dt.$$
$I$ is the imaginary part of the complex integral 
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{t\log\Gamma(\frac14+\frac{it}{2})}{(\frac14+t^2)^2}\,dt$$
using the usual branch of the logarithm of $\Gamma(s)$. Integrating by parts 
$$=\frac12\int_0^\infty \log\Gamma(\tfrac14+\tfrac{it}{2})\,d\Bigl\{-\frac{1}{\frac14+t^2}\Bigr\}=
\Bigl.-\frac{1}{2(\frac14+t^2)}\log \Gamma(\tfrac14+\tfrac{it}{2})\Bigr|_{t=0}^\infty+\frac12\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\frac14+t^2}\frac{i}{2}\frac{\Gamma'(\frac14+\frac{it}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac14+\frac{it}{2})}\,dt$$
$$=2\log\Gamma(1/4)+\frac{i}{4}\int_0^\infty \frac{\Gamma'(\frac14+\frac{it}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac14+\frac{it}{2})}\frac{dt}{\frac14+t^2}.$$
We have
$$-\frac{\Gamma'(s)}{\Gamma(s)}=\gamma+\frac{1}{s}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\Bigl(\frac{1}{s+n}-\frac{1}{n}\Bigr).$$
It is easy to justify the interchange here so that 
$$=2\log\Gamma(1/4)-\frac{i}{4}\Bigl\{\gamma\int_0^\infty \frac{dt}{\frac14+t^2}+
\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\frac14+\frac{it}{2}}\frac{dt}{\frac14+t^2}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty 
\int_0^\infty \Bigl(\frac{1}{\frac14+\frac{it}{2}+n}-\frac{1}{n}\Bigr)\frac{dt}{\frac14+t^2}
\Bigr\}$$
With Mathematica we find 
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{dt}{\frac14+t^2}=\pi,\quad \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\frac14+\frac{it}{2}}\frac{dt}{\frac14+t^2}=2\pi-4i,$$
$$\int_0^\infty \Bigl(\frac{1}{\frac14+\frac{it}{2}+n}-\frac{1}{n}\Bigr)\frac{dt}{\frac14+t^2}=-\frac{\pi+i\log(1+4n)}{n(2n+1)}.$$
Taking the imaginary part we obtain 
$$I=-\frac14\Bigl\{\pi\gamma+2\pi-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\pi}{n(2n+1)}\Bigr\}$$
For the sum in $n$ we get with Mathematica
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n(2n+1)}=2-2\log 2.$$
It follows that 
$$I=-\frac14 \bigl\{\pi\gamma+2\pi-2\pi+2\pi\log2\bigr\}=-\frac{\pi}{4}(\gamma+\log 4).$$

The evaluations with Mathematica are not difficult to prove.

Comment: Unfortunately, the output of the Mathematica's code N[-Pi/4*(EulerGamma + Log[4])] equals $-1.54214$. This is not in accordance with the numeric value  NIntegrate[t * Arg[Gamma[1/4 + I*t/2]]/(1/4 + t^2)^2, {t, 0, Infinity}, 
 AccuracyGoal -> 3, WorkingPrecision -> 15], i. e. $ -1.62060929754175$.

Comment: @user64494 You can not use here Arg[Gamma[]] because this is not the continuous argument.  use instead Im[LogGamma[   and you will get my value.

Comment: Can you elaborate your comment? The plots Plot[Arg[Gamma[1/4 + I * t/2]], {t, 0, 10}] and Plot[Im[LogGamma[1/4 + I * t/2]], {t, 0, 10}] are identical

Comment: @user64494 Plot it from 0 to 20,  the problem is that the argument of gamma can be defined as a continuous function  that sometimes cross  pi,  3pi  and so on.  Of course you can consider the integral with the discontinuous argument.  But usually when one speaks about the argument of Gamma one uses the continuous one.

Comment: The question is unclearly formulated: usually $\arg z$ stands for the main value of the argument of a complex number $z$ and the Arg[z] command realizes it.